# C++ Program crashing when trying to rearrange array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, crash

I'm still relatively new to c++. I am trying to write a program that takes an array of numbers and reverses the order of those numbers in the array with a function. The program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

void reverse(int *array, int size);

int main() {

    int Array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int size = sizeof(Array) / 4;
    reverse(Array, size);

    return 0;
}

void reverse(int *array, int size) {
    int Array2[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Array2[i + size] = array[i];
        array[i + size] = Array2[i + size];
    };
}
```

When I run this program, it crashes and I'm not sure why. If anyone can help my figure out why it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array2[i + size]`

You're accessing out-of-bounds, no matter the value of `i`.

You probably meant `Array2[size - 1 - i]` to iterate the array backwards. (`size - 1` is the index of the last element.)

Answer (score 2):

Zenith has it, but there are a few points and quick hacks worth noting to help you out.

```
#include <iostream>

//using namespace std; don't need this, and using namespace std is overkill and often 
// causes problems. It pulls in a  lot of stuff that may conflict, case in point 
// std::reverse now becomes reverse. Which reverse will you get? Your reverse or the standard 
// library's reverse? Only pull in what you need, for example 
using std::cout; // still not used, but makes a good example.

void reverse(int *array, int size) 
{
    // no need for the other array and another loop. You can swap each element for 
    //it's counterpart in the upper half of the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < size /2 ; i++) // only need to go half way. Other half was 
                                       // already swapped doing the first half.
    {
        int temp = array[i]; // store a temporary copy of element i
        array[i] = array[size-1-i]; // replace element i with it's counterpart 
                                    // from the second half of the array
        array[size-1-i] = temp; // replace the counterpart of i with the copy of i     
        // or call std::swap(array[i], array[size-1-i]);
    };
}
int main() {

    int Array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    // int size = sizeof(Array) / 4; using 4 here can trip you up on a computer with 
    // a different sized int
    int size = sizeof(Array) / sizeof(Array[0]); 
    // dividing the size of the array by the size of an element in the array will always 
    // get you the correct size
    reverse(Array, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your in depth analysis! Very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

by using swap you will get a much nicer solution which is also more efficient

```
void reverse(int *array, int size) {
   for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++) {
        std::swap(array[i],array[size-1-i]);
   };
}
```

Comment: But your code swaps twice, so you end up with the same array.

Comment: yes you are right - thanks for pointing that out, I changed it

Answer (score 0):

When you say `int size = sizeof(Array) / 4;`, `size` is now `(5 * sizeof(int)) / 4`. That's how the `sizeof` operator works (at least when applied to arrays).

So `size` is probably 5, assuming a 4-byte `int`. Now, you get to `reverse` and its argument `size` is also 5.

You get to the `for` loop, and even at the first iteration, you have `Array2[5] = /* something */` and `array[5] = /* something */`, both of which are buffer overruns.

Also, your `reverse` function doesn't actually do any reversing. Try this:

```
void reverse(int *arr, int size);

int main()
{
    int Array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int size = sizeof(Array) / sizeof(int);
    reverse(Array, size);

    return 0;
}

void reverse(int *arr, int size)
{
    int temp[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        temp[size - 1 - i] = arr[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = temp[i];
}
```